# Time zone conversion between TZ aware datetimestamp

Tags: python, pytz

I have bunch of datetime stamps in multiple timezone, similar to 2017-03-02T18:00:00+04:00 which are TZ aware.

The idea is to convert each of them to UTC TZ aware format like 2017-03-02T14:00:00+00:00

Is there a way to detect time zone from GMT offset and then pytz for the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.You should use `astimezone` method with the desired timezone as below:

```
import pytz
from dateutil import parser

dt = parser.parse('2017-03-02T18:00:00+04:00')
print(dt.astimezone(pytz.utc))
```

The result will be:

> `2017-03-02 14:00:00+00:00`